# CentOS + apache subdomain always redirect to main domain

Tags: apache, centos, centos6

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sales@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dev@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.example
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dev.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dev.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dev.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

locations of two projects are

```
/var/www/html/exmaple
```

and

```
/var/www/html/dev.example
```

I've create A record 'dev' to the same IP that's the primary domain is assigned.
Where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the NameVirtualHost Directive in httpd.conf before using the same host for two Virtualhosts

Add `NameVirtualHost *:80` to your httpd.conf

Comment: It would be deprecated